# Retrieving an array back from a jquery.load() function and displaying in separate divs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

I have the following jquery.load() function

```
function updateSecondChart(first, second, third, forth){
            $("#test").load("/application/views/public/FactoryData.php?site=" + first + "&time=" + second + "&unit=" + third + "&device=" + forth); }
```

The function works fine and sends parameters to another page so I can do some database queries and then it returns a result and outputs it in the div called test.

The problem i have is i want to return an array with 10 or so rows as the result and then place each of the rows in its own div without having to make 10 requests.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: You're going to want to use `$.get()` and not `$.load()` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the other AJAX-related jQuery functions (`.get()`, `.post()`, or `.ajax()`) and then handle the response however you need to in the callback function.